# onClickListener in onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, button

Is it wrong to do that or will it work just fine? I'm trying to make every relative layout clickable and when you click on it it takes you to a new page where the mGameTitle and mReleaseDate are passed to this new activity.
I'm doubting if it will work 'cause I'm getting an error with View.OnClickListener; ***must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener***

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderUpcoming viewHolderUpcoming, int i) {
    Game currentGame = listOfGames.get(i);
    viewHolderUpcoming.mReleaseDate.setText(currentGame.getReleaseDate());
    viewHolderUpcoming.mGameTitle.setText(currentGame.getTitle());


    viewHolderUpcoming.mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       //Intent intent = new Intent(this, GamePage.class);

    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you need to implement `onClick(View)`.

```
viewHolderUpcoming.mLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = v.getContext();
        //TODO: Implementation
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh thanks, so a onClickListener in onBindViewHolder is completely normal or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, there is no other way to do it afaik.

Comment: Thx, sorry if i'm bothering you, but with what do i replace "this" in my intent ?

Comment: @karaokyo there is other way. Implementing View.OnClickListener in ViewHolder class with declaring interface instead of onBindViewHolder, which has advantage of implementation being present in fragment/activity code instead of adapter code

Comment: Wouldn't that typically require getting the position of the item? Which means there would still need to be a click listener assigned in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: @karaokyo not if implementation of OnClick returns layout position. Like this : http://pastebin.com/mSpFetur .